# Keyboard doesn't hide when segue on UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uistoryboardsegue

In storyboard I've connected from `UITextField` to another view. In my code I set a target for `UITextField` on `UIControlEventEditingChanged`. I also wrote some code in shouldPerformSegue and prepareForSegue.(only in some condition It can perform segue)
My problem is that before performing segue, `UITextField` becomes first responder and shows keyboard when it goes to the new view controller.
I have tried `[self.view endEditing:YES]` and `resignFirstResponder` for all textFields but it didn't change anything at all!
Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: "before performing segue, UITextField becomes first responder and shows keyboard when it goes to the new view controller" but that can only be because you are making it first responder. It would hardly happen spontaneously.

Comment: Maybe my question is ambiguous. I would never call become first responder  on this field. I have multiple textfields that should have access to the keyboard and when I edit any of them and then tap on the mentioned one, keyboard remains up in the following segue.

Comment: It didn't help me @SatishA !

Comment: are you using "textfield-didChangeCharectersInRange" method?

Comment: I use textField- DidBeginEditing and shouldBeginEditing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by placing a button on textField, whenever I want to perform segue, I disable textfield (if needed) and change view on button touch!